# Clojurescript react extension doesn't work with firefox, works with chromium, how to debug further?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, chromium, clojurescript

I am trying to build a browser extension using clojurescript and re-agent (wrapper around react). The code is very simple [(complete source and repro steps here)](https://github.com/charignon/cljs-extension-react-issue), mostly copied from a re-agent example:

```
(ns clext2.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]))

(defn timer-component []
  (let [seconds-elapsed (r/atom 0)]
    (fn []
      (js/setTimeout #(do (println "timeout") (swap! seconds-elapsed inc)) 1000)
      [:div "Seconds Elapsed: " @seconds-elapsed])))

(let [app (js/document.createElement "div")
      _ (js/document.body.appendChild app)]
   (r/render [timer-component] app))
```

I compiled this with the `:simple` optimization flag, copied the generated js into the example code published by Mozilla: https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Creating-Packages, and loaded the extension on chromium and firefox.

### Observations

When I test with figwheel locally, the counter renders in both chromium and firefox.

When I navigate to a real page (not using figwheel):

- With firefox, the counter loads but does not increment (`timeout` is printed once)
- With chrome, the counter loads and increments (`timeout` is printed every second)

### Expected behavior

I would expect the counter to get visibly increment with firefox and it does not.

### Browser Versions

- Chromium (71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) Manjaro Linux (64-bit))
- Firefox (64.0 for manjaro).

### My question

I am not sure how to debug this further, what can I try next?

Comment: I can repro the issue with the latest firefox and chrome on mac os (chrome works, firefox doesn't).

Answer (score -1):

You are conflating the view (visual aspect) with the events (timer stuff).  You should keep then separate.  Please see the r[e-frame docs](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame).

Comment: I purposefully didn't separate the two for the sake of providing a complete minimum verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the issue that I was seeing.